# Symfony2 - Querybuilder error - Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Stumped on an error and can't figure out how to fix this.

This my error:

`FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object in /.../Entity/BlogRepository.php line 31`

line 31: `->setParameter('categoryTitle', $category->getTitle())`

Can I get some help on what's wrong with my query? (should be getting posts by category)

query

```
public function getBlogsByCategory($category)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('blog')
        ->where('blog.category = :categoryTitle')
        ->setParameter('categoryTitle', $category->getTitle())
        ->orderBy('blog.created', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/{category}", name="AcmeDemoBundle_category")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Page:category.html.twig")
 */
public function categoryAction($category = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $blogs = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog')
        ->getBlogsByCategory($category);

    if (!$blogs) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find blog posts');
    }

    return array(
        'blogs'    => $blogs,
    );
}
```

Twig

```
<li id="" class=""><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_category', 
{ 'category': 'Category1' }) }}">Category 1</a></li>
```

Comment: In your code `$category` is not an object so you can't call any method on it.

Comment: Do you construct link to that action by passing `category` title?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by construct link, but yes I pass in the title from Twig. Updated the question with the Twig info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are createing link with category title so you get a string in your controller and not `Category` object. Change your action to something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/{categoryTitle}", name="AcmeDemoBundle_category")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Page:category.html.twig")
 */
public function categoryAction($categoryTitle)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $blogs = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog')
        ->getBlogsByCategoryTitle($categoryTitle);

    if (!$blogs) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find blog posts');
    }

    return array(
        'blogs'    => $blogs,
    );
}
```

And repository:

```
public function getBlogsByCategoryTitle($categoryTitle)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('blog')
        ->leftJoin('blog.category','category')
        ->where('category.title = :categoryTitle')
        ->setParameter('categoryTitle', $categoryTitle)
        ->orderBy('blog.created', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

And Twig:

```
<li id="" class=""><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_category', 
{ 'categoryTitle': 'Category1' }) }}">Category 1</a></li>
```

Comment: Have tried this but `blog.categoryTitle` in Repository does not exist in my entity. And getting the `Invalid parameter: token blog.categoryTitle is not defined in the query.` error

Comment: Have tried using `categoryTitle` instead but that just brings up an empty array.

Comment: My bad. I have updated my aswer. Changed `getBlogsByCategoryTitle` function.

Comment: This works! Can you explain to me why leftJoin is needed here and the other queryBuilder solution didn't work?

Comment: I assumed that ther is a relation between `Post` and `Category` (ManyToOne).

Comment: Just trying to understand here, there is a relation (bi-directional OnetoMany/ManytoOne), but why is leftJoin needed and the other way didn't work?

Comment: This works because you dont have category title in `Post` entity. You have only a reference to related `Category` object. If you want find `Post` by category title you need to join `Category` object to get a title.

Answer (score 1):

Your action defaults and allows the category to be `null`.

Your repository also allows the category to be `null` as it has no type hint set.

This means that your action and repository can be called even though there is no category being supplied, meaning that your category (which is `null`) has no title.